ESP32 ADC attenuation values
I am new to ESP32 and I need to use the ADC of ESP32 in one of my application.
I received the below image from this reference.

The document says that the ADC reference voltage is 1.1V to measure highe voltages ESP32 uses a variable gain attenuation.
My question is when my input is grater than 1.1V,can I connect it directly to ADC without using
any down converting circuit like a voltage divider.

Yes. In ESP32 The attenuation does the same as a voltage divider.
The attenuation happens on the adc input signal rather than doing anything with the reference. As documentation indicates, for DB_0, there isn't any attenuation and you can measure almost to ref voltage. It says 950mV as the measurement after that up to ref is nonlinear.
If you use ESP32, for DB_11, you can measure up to 2450mV without any issue. If you need a higher range, you can use ESP32-S3 which can measure up to 3100mV for DB_11.
If you need any higher voltages, then you have to add an external voltage divider to lower the voltage and bring it into the range.
One thing to be mindful of is that the adc pins on ESP32 can draw a big leakage current. This means you have to use either low register values for the divider or, use a buffer after the divider to feed the required current to the ADC pin.

Thank you.DB_11 says 150mV to 2.45V.If my input is less than 150mV what will happen

@Confused below 150 mV, expect at least a non-linear response. If you're lucky it will be monotonic, but may not be. It may well be offset so you won't read 0 for 0 input. That's why it's not specified, it's not specified. Seeing how one ESP32 behaves may not tell you how they all behave.

@Neil_UK,on a safer side I need to make my minimum value of input grater than 150mV.Please confirm.

The voltage can go to 0 without the issue. Those ranges are for the linear result. Below 150mV, you don't get a very good reliable reading. But from the hardware side, it is ok to connect 0 volts to that pin.
